# JavaScript Concatenating regular expression to string

Tags: javascript, types

Recently I have notice the following code of my colleague:

```
$.post(baseUrl + /resource/, data, function() {
    // ...
});
```

What has suprised me is that he is concatenating regular expression `/resource/` to a string `baseUrl` and it works correctly. Is a good or bad practice to do what?

Comment: There doesn't look to be any reason for that to be a regular expression. It would be much less confusing if it was a simple string instead. Bad practice, I'd say

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/toString

Comment: Bad practice because it's confusing! But man, is it sneaky and saves bytes. Unfortunately good or bad practice aren't usually the best fit for questions at SO